# Has the F-35 Lightning II overheating problem been resolved?

Tags: aircraft-certification, f-35, aircraft-production

[This](http://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/547086/RAF-s-150million-stealth-fighter-jet-could-shut-down-after-overheating-fears) is one of the sources explaining the F-35 overheating problem. Has this been resolved?

Are the constant problems, that are being reported about this type normal for an aircraft like this?

Comment: I like how the main image on the page isn't an F-35.

Comment: Yes, that certainly is journalistic achievment par excellence, the pulitzer must be right around the corner.

Comment: This is the Daily Express we're talking about. The only thing remarkable about that story is that it doesn't [blame immigrants or have something to do with the death of Princess Diana](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1351&bih=1090&q=daily+express+headlines&oq=daily+express+headlines&gs_l=img.3..0j0i30k1j0i8i30k1l6j0i24k1l2.607.9019.0.9108.29.21.3.5.5.0.161.1570.16j3.19.0....0...1ac.1j2.64.img..2.26.1520.0.Arbq3cg9Lbs).

Comment: It hasn't been solved. https://mainichi.jp/english/articles/20190417/p2a/00m/0na/006000c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As to the first question, it appears as fuel cooling of electronic components and other equipment is integral in the F-35 design, all branches of the armed services will not be able to remedy this problem and it will have to be solved with only fueling the aircraft with cold fuel.  The Air Force has opted to use fuel trucks painted white in order to keep fuel cool while on the ground and it may require refrigeration equipment in fuel tank farms at F-35 bases at an additional cost to the program.

The fuel problems for the F-35 are but [one of several hundred faults, shortcomings and outright vulnerabilities with the troubled Joint Strike Fighter program](http://www.dote.osd.mil/pub/reports/FY2016/pdf/dod/2016f35jsf.pdf).  While developmental issues are common in new aircraft programs, none so far have been this serious, so numerous and so overbudget without being killed.

Comment: Are there any comparisons of such programs? From where do you have the information, that other programs like this were killed?

Comment: The A-12 Avenger, the RAH-66 Comanche, and nearly the ATF/F-22 quickly come to mind.

Comment: As a yardstick for comparison, the F-14 airplane went from concept to new F-14As rolling off the production lines in Bethpage and entering the fleet in 51 months.